# Automatically assigning a value based on a different table

Tags: python, pandas

(example) Primary table:

| name | win/loss |
| --- | --- |
| Patrick | 1 |
| Phillip | 0 |
| Patrick | 1 |
| Phillip | 0 |
| Patrick | 0 |

Derived table via `.groupby('name') * 100`

| name | winrate |
| --- | --- |
| Patrick | 67% |
| Phillip | 0% |

Desired table:

| name | win/loss | winrate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patrick | 1 | 67% |
| Phillip | 0 | 0% |
| Patrick | 1 | 67% |
| Phillip | 0 | 0% |
| Patrick | 0 | 67% |

Explanation: There are too many names, not just Patrick and Phillip in the database so I need to do it automatically. I can't just append derived table's win rate column.

I assume I could either do it via iteration, or I could somehow tell Pandas "if name = Patrick then assign 67% to column 'winrate'", but I don't know how. Thank you a ton!

Comment: Have you looked at the [join/merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) tutorial in the Pandas documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few ways to do it. One of them is merge and among other is map

here is a solution using map

```
df['winrate']=df['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['winrate'])
df
```

```
    name    win/loss    winrate
0   Patrick     1   67%
1   Phillip     0   0%
2   Patrick     1   67%
3   Phillip     0   0%
4   Patrick     0   67%
```